# How can we find out value of webview.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction using javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have to play video (**HTML5**) on **iOS** in autoplay mode, but for that we need to set `webview.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` as `FALSE`.

Is there any way to check the value of `webview.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction=FALSE` or `TRUE`, using `JavaScript`?

Comment: Have you check that apple support auto play mode for HTML5?

Comment: call `video.play();` then `setTimeout` to check the playback state?

Comment: @user2590583 is webview.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false is auto playing the content?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible as apple doc say

> **User Control of Downloads Over Cellular Networks**
>   In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it.
>   ref:- http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me again try to explain my question

Comment: We are trying to know at app side whether our video will run in autoplay mode or not. This will help us to know whether audio was on or off at video load time. Can you please suggest how can we achieve this.

Comment: Further, we tried to achieve this by checking webview.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction value at load time. We were not able to get the value using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

autoplay will work if you also set muted, the problem is as soon as you turn off the mute, the video stops.